# Python and C++ code comparison

Tags: c++, python

I have the following `python` code

```
for m,n in [(-1,1),(-1,0),(-1,-1)] if 0<=i+m<b and 0<=j+n<l and image[i+m][j+n] == '0']
```

`image` is array defined and `i` and `j` is also defined.

Following is how I have converted this into `C++`

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > direction;
direction.push_back(std::make_pair(-1,1));
direction.push_back(std::make_pair(-1,0));
direction.push_back(std::make_pair(-1,-1));
for ( std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >::iterator itr = direction.begin(); 
                   itr != direction.end(); ++itr) {
    int m = (*itr).first;
    int n = (*itr).second;
   if ( (0 <= i + m && i + m < width ) && 
                   (0 <= j + n && j + n < width ) && 
                   image[i + m][j + n ] == 0) {
}
```

Is this conversion correct?

Comment: you can use itr->first syntax instead of (*itr).first, although it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: image is defined as ['10001','10100','00000','00000','00111','00100','00100']

Comment: In the `C++` code? What kind of data is that? 2D array with `char`s ?

Comment: I am using int and not char like std::vector<std::vector<int> > image;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another person remarked, the `width` used in two places is probably incorrect.

Assuming that, here's a comparision of direct translation from Python versus C++-like code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void likeCPlusPlus()
{
    int i = 666, j = 666, width = 666, height = 666, image[666][666];

    for( int dy = 1;  dy >= -1;  --dy )
    {
        int const   dx  = -1;
        int const   x   = i + dx;
        int const   y   = j + dy;

        if(
            0 <= x && x < width &&
            0 <= y && y < height &&
            image[x][y] == 0
            )
        {}
    }
}

void likePythonInCPlusPlus()
{
    int i = 666, j = 666, width = 666, image[666][666];

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > direction;
    direction.push_back(std::make_pair(-1,1));
    direction.push_back(std::make_pair(-1,0));
    direction.push_back(std::make_pair(-1,-1));
    for ( std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >::iterator itr = direction.begin(); 
                       itr != direction.end(); ++itr)
    {
        int m = (*itr).first;
        int n = (*itr).second;
        if ( (0 <= i + m && i + m < width ) && 
                       (0 <= j + n && j + n < width ) && 
                       image[i + m][j + n ] == 0)
        {}
    }
}

int main()
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost. You have two differences: in `Python`, you have `i+m<b` and `j+n<l`, which makes me think `b!=l`.

In your `C++` code, you have `i + m < width` and `j + n < width`, where `width` is the same.

If `width == b == l`, then everything's fine.

Actually, depends on how `image` is defined. The `image[i + m][j + n ] == 0` is what bothers me (the part with `==0`)

As the @Avinash comment says, image is `vector< vector< int > >`, so the code is fine.

Comment: and they are the same as `width`? Plus, in Python, you compare the `image` with `char`s (`== '0'`), and here with `int`s  ( `== 0` ). If this is correct, everything else is fine.

Comment: additionally the python snippet is a list comprehension so OP should probably push the m and n into a list if the condition of the if is true

Comment: @soulcheck - probably yes, but we don't know what's after the `if`'s condition.

Comment: @KirilKirov aye, though we know that the python snippet ends with ] and has list comprehension syntax so whatever he does with m and n will get pushed some list

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build that vector at runtime, if it's really a hardcoded constant.
Just do:

```
const std::pair<int,int> list[] = { {-1,1}, {-1,0}, {-1,-1} };
for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(list)/sizeof(*list); ++index)
{
    int m = list[index].first;
    int n = list[index].second;
    ...
}
```

if you're allowed C++0x, or

```
const struct { int first, second; } list[] = { {-1,1}, {-1,0}, {-1,-1} };
...
```

if not.
Otherwise, the translation looks plausible.

Comment: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int for list declaration

Comment: Which version, (I posted two), which line, and with or without C++0x support? NB, I just edited to qualify `std::pair`, since I omitted `using namespace std;` along with the includes etc.

Comment: following is the real error : error C2552: 'list' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

Comment: The first version, which specifically requires C++0x support for extended initializer lists? Try the second version of the declaration instead then, it's marginally more verbose but doesn't require C++0x support

Answer (score 1):

If you don't try to reproduce Python idioms in C++, the code can be simplified to:

```
for (int n = 1; n >= -1; --n) {
    const int m = -1;
    if (...
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works under c++1z:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
for( auto [m,n] : vector<tuple<int,int> >{{-1,1}, {-1,0}, {-1,-1}})
  if(0<=i+m<b and 0<=j+n<l and image[i+m][j+n] == '0'){}
```